# How do I replace below for loop code with Java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

In the below code i am trying to create a Set based on some conditions. I want to use java 8 streams and replace this code involving for loops. Any code example/sample will be much appreciated.

```
Set<OwnerEntity> entities = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for(Account acct : accounts){
    String acctNumber = acct.getAccountNumber();

    OwnerEntity oEntity = new OwnerEntity();
    oEntity.setAccount(acct);
    oEntity.setName(acct.getName());

    for (StatusModel sts : stsModels) {
        if ( sts.egtStatus() != null &&
                (acctNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(sts.getAccountNumber()))) {
            oEntity.addStatusModel(sts);
        }
    }

    entities.add(oEntity);
}
```

Comment: To define precisely, do expand upon the implementation of `oEntity.addStatusModel(sts)`.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to make in two steps, like so :

### First Step

If you note, you have that block of code which is repeated each time :

```
for (StatusModel sts : stsModels) {
    if ( sts.egtStatus() != null &&
            (acctNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(sts.getAccountNumber()))) {
        oEntity.addStatusModel(sts);
    }
}
```

In this case, you can group by the `status`, then you can call with your map to get the list of `StatusModel` by `accountNumber`, to do this you can use :

```
Map<String, List<StatusModel>> map = stsModels.stream()
        .filter(sts -> sts.getStatus() != null)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StatusModel::getAccountNumber));
```

Or more precise, you can group with status in lowerCase :

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.getStatus().toLowerCase()));
```

### Second Step

Then, you can loop over the accounts and create a new `OwnerEntity` like so :

```
Set<OwnerEntity> entities = accounts.stream()
        .map(acct ->
                new OwnerEntity(acct,
                        acct.getName(),
                        map.getOrDefault(acct.getAccountNumber().toLowerCase(), Collections.emptyList())))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Note: I used `toLowerCase()` in both side `groupingBy` and `getOrDefault` to avoid using looping over the list and check by using `equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: Are there multiple `StatusModel`s per account number. That'd require a `Collectors.groupingBy` if you're going to change the algorithm.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I was thinking about that, but after reading the question again, I find that the OP even he has a unique account names, or he crash the first value

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline no no Sorry, the OP use `add` not `set` its my bad, I think he has a List of `StatusModel` I will rollback my answer

Comment: Consider replacing the default value `null` with `Collections.emptyList()`. On the other hand, converting to a specific type of case (lower or upper) is not more of a choice, but a must for the `equalsIgnoreCase` check using the above approach, so it would be better to include that code in the suggestion with the comment to why it's required.

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like:

```
Set<OwnerEntity> entities = accounts.stream()
    .map(acct -> {
        String acctNumber = acct.getAccountNumber();

        OwnerEntity oEntity = new OwnerEntity();
        oEntity.setAccount(acct);
        oEntity.setName(acct.getName());

        stsModels.stream()
           // You can do .filter as a two-parter with Objects::nonNull
           .filter(sts ->
              sts.egtStatus() != null &&
              acctNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(sts.getAccountNumber())
           )
           .forEach(oEntity::addStatusModel);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

It's not much of an improvement, but that's streams for you.